# jQuery increase data attribute value for each items

Tags: jquery, foreach

I'm trying to make a jQuery program that increases the data attribute value for each list item.

```
var current = 0;
$(".kunde-logo-listing").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("data-wow-delay", current);
   current++;
});
```

I tried to use the above and the output is as follows:

```
data-wow-delay="0"
data-wow-delay="1"
data-wow-delay="2"
data-wow-delay="3"
data-wow-delay="4"
```

But the output I'm trying to get should be:

```
data-wow-delay="000ms"
data-wow-delay="100ms"
data-wow-delay="200ms"
data-wow-delay="300ms"
data-wow-delay="400ms"
```

Anyone got an idea how to make this work? Is it something with concatenating the value to a string of "ms" ?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you really need the leading zeroes on the first one? Can it be `0ms` instead?

Comment: @Barmar: That....wasn't the question that came to **my** mind. :-)

Comment: Instead of incrementing `current` by `1` each time, increment it by `100`: `current += 100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var current = 0;
$(".kunde-logo-listing").each(function() {
    $(this).data("wow-delay", current+"00ms");
    current++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as follows:

```
var current = 0;
$(".kunde-logo-listing").each(function () {
    $(this).data("wow-delay", current++ * 100 + "ms");
    //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```